# Flutter on pressed didn't work with animated button

Tags: android, ios, flutter, kotlin, dart

this code is for 4 floating action button but the problem is that the onPressed didn't work with the 3 animated button and work with the fixed button

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController animationController;
  Animation degOneTranslationAnimation, degTwoTranslationAnimation, degThreeTranslationAnimation;
  Animation rotationAnimation;

  double getRadiansFromDegree(double degree) {
    double unitRadian = 57.295779513;
    return degree / unitRadian;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    animationController = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250));
    degOneTranslationAnimation = TweenSequence(<TweenSequenceItem>[
      TweenSequenceItem<double>(tween: Tween<double >(begin: 0.0,end: 1.2), weight: 75.0),
      TweenSequenceItem<double>(tween: Tween<double>(begin: 1.2,end: 1.0), weight: 25.0),
    ])
        .animate(animationController);
    degTwoTranslationAnimation = TweenSequence(<TweenSequenceItem>[
      TweenSequenceItem<double>(tween: Tween<double >(begin: 0.0,end: 1.4), weight: 55.0),
      TweenSequenceItem<double>(tween: Tween<double>(begin: 1.4,end: 1.0), weight: 45.0)
    ])
        .animate(animationController);
    degThreeTranslationAnimation = TweenSequence(<TweenSequenceItem>[
      TweenSequenceItem<double>(tween: Tween<double >(begin: 0.0,end: 1.75), weight: 35.0),
      TweenSequenceItem<double>(tween: Tween<double>(begin: 1.75,end: 1.0), weight: 65.0)
    ])
        .animate(animationController);
    rotationAnimation = Tween<double>(begin: 180.0, end: 0.0)
        .animate(CurvedAnimation(parent: animationController, curve: Curves.easeOut));
    super.initState();
    animationController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width: size.width,
        height: size.height,
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Positioned(
              right: 30,
              bottom: 30,
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Transform.translate(
                    offset: Offset.fromDirection(
                        getRadiansFromDegree(270), degOneTranslationAnimation.value * 100),
                    child: Transform(
                      transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(getRadiansFromDegree(rotationAnimation.value))
                        ..scale(degOneTranslationAnimation.value),
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: CircularButton(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        width: 50,
                        height: 50,
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.add,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Transform.translate(
                    offset: Offset.fromDirection(
                        getRadiansFromDegree(225), degOneTranslationAnimation.value * 100),
                    child: Transform(
                      transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(getRadiansFromDegree(rotationAnimation.value))
                        ..scale(degOneTranslationAnimation.value),
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: CircularButton(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        width: 50,
                        height: 50,
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.camera_alt,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Transform.translate(
                    offset: Offset.fromDirection(
                        getRadiansFromDegree(180), degOneTranslationAnimation.value * 100),
                    child: Transform(
                      transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(getRadiansFromDegree(rotationAnimation.value))
                        ..scale(degOneTranslationAnimation.value),
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: CircularButton(
                        color: Colors.orangeAccent,
                        width: 50,
                        height: 50,
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.person,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Transform(
                    transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(getRadiansFromDegree(rotationAnimation.value)),
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: CircularButton(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      width: 60,
                      height: 60,
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.menu,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      onClick: () {
                        if (animationController.isCompleted) {
                          animationController.reverse();
                        } else {
                          animationController.forward();
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

that's my complete code you can paste it and test it i need some help because the onPressed didn't work with the animated button and only works with fixed button and thank you[image]

Answer (score 0):

I could not use run your code since I do not have any idea about "CircularButton" which is probably custom widget you have created.

I can suggest you to use [fab_circular_menu](https://pub.dev/packages/fab_circular_menu) if it fits your needs.

Happy coding.

Comment: i saw this it's not beautiful you can download the code from here https://github.com/letsdoit07/flutter_animated_fab_menu/tree/master/lib

Comment: I tried different things but no luck then found out that it is a common issue in Flutter.
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27587